# Google Share Button grabbing all images from the page

Tags: html, google-plus, facebook-opengraph, share-button

My aim is to use the google share button to allow people sharing contents from my blog. I used the google share snippet like here :

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<? echo $permalink; ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**Context :**

Each article in my blog is actually a restaurant review. 
A classical restaurant review page contains a slider with `<img>` tags. My sidebar also contains a slider with `<img>` tags for recent posts. 
To customise my facebook share button I use Open Graph tags like so :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://grain2sel.fr/france/iledefrance/paris/mamie-burger" />
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/108380150528993749302"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Mamie Burger - Grain2Sel" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Est-ce que votre grand-mère vous fait souvent des Burgers ? Moi j’ai trouvé la grand-mère à la pointe de la modernité et des..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://grain2sel.fr/france/iledefrance/paris/mamie-burger" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Grain2Sel" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/grain2sel.fr/" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Américain" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="Burger" />
<meta property="article:tag" content="En famille" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Paris" />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-12-11T12:28:44+01:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2017-03-13T15:01:40+01:00" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2017-03-13T15:01:40+01:00" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="238884123187421" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://grain2sel.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mamie_burger_1-1280x720.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="870" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="489" />
```

From what I read, I need precisely for google :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Mamie Burger - Grain2Sel" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Est-ce que votre grand-mère vous fait souvent des Burgers ? Moi j’ai trouvé la grand-mère à la pointe de la modernité et des..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://grain2sel.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mamie_burger_1-1280x720.jpg" />
```

**Issue :**

While the title and the description are nicely exposed in the share popup box, all images from my page are also put. 
The first image offered is the one in the og tag. Then all images from the restaurant slider and finally all images from recent posts slider.
Those last images are clearly not wanted here because they are unrelated with the current article.

**Details :**

I also tried with schema.org tags without any improvement.

**Question :**

> Is it possible to force the sharer to only use the image I chose with
>   og tag ?

_

> or is it possible to remove the other images from the parsing of the
>   sharer ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 3):

You can't tell Google+ to exclude images. If you don't want an image to be an option you will have to not include it in the HTML response. You should use [+Snippets](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) to tell Google+ what images you want to be used but Google+ doesn't guarantee which one it will use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I use +Snippets and it works well. That means that the image I want to appear on the share page is the first one proposed but it's followed by all other images in my page.